# GitLab CI Cannot Install/Use PhantomJS

Tags: continuous-integration, phantomjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm currently developing a web app using Flask, and needing to use PhantomJS in one of the tests. I use GitLab for the remote git repository and using GitLab CI as the CI tool.

Unfortunately, it seems that I can't get GitLab CI's shared runner to install and run PhantomJS. It's output:

[Failed PhantomJS Run Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lROwU.png)

A snippet from my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: python:2.7.11

before_script:
  - ...
  - mkdir ~/tmp
  - pushd ~/tmp
  - wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
  - tar xf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
  - mv $PHANTOM_JS phantomjs
  - ln -s ~/tmp/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
  - phantomjs --version
  - popd
  - ...
```

`$Phantom_JS` refers to a specific version of PhantomJS.

Does anyone know the solution? Or is there any other method to install and run PhantomJS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the bug is on myself. I failed to find out earlier that Gitlab CI is built on 64-bit machine. I downloaded the 32-bit version that somehow doesn't work on the runner.

Comment: sudo npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt <-- will download and install the latest binary for the correct system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar in a ruby image [Dockerfile](https://gitlab.devfu.com/devfu/dockerfiles/blob/master/ci/2.3/Dockerfile#L17-21) and can confirm that sometimes it just doesn't download the expected zip file.

```
RUN cd /tmp && \
    curl -OL https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 && \
    tar xjf phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs && \
    mv phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin && \
    rm -r phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64*
```

As far as I can tell, the bitbucket URL redirects to an authenticated S3 url that sometimes 404s.

I've resorted to running the image locally with `docker run -it IMAGE /bin/bash` and verifying that phantomjs is installed using `which phantomjs` and `phantomjs --version` after *every* build. If the install hasn't worked, I build the container again.

I've noticed that hitting the download URL in a browser (which will download the file locally) BEFORE running the container build increases the likelihood of success. I'd love to see a "better" solution.

Comment: You should see the image: The runner has successfully downloaded and uncompressed the tar file, but then the PhantomJS binary couldn't be found afterwards... I've never experienced failure in downloading the tar file from Bitbucket.

Comment: In my experience the file does seem to download & decompress properly, but the file that winds up `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs` is not executable, so `phantomjs --version` causes an error. Running through the script manually is how I found out that the download was actually not successful in these cases.